# Как решить задачу с помощью множеств:"Проверить введенную пользователем строку на наличие недопустимых символов."

Tags: python

В качестве первого символа допустимы только буквы и знак подчеркивания. Остальные символы могут быть буквами, цифрами и знаком подчеркивания.

код программы:

```
import re
def chk_first(s): 
    c = s[0]  
    if not (c.isalpha() or c=='_'): 
        return c 
    return None 
def chk_rest(s): 
    pat = r'([^а-яёa-z_0-9])'
    return re.findall(pat, s[1:], flags=re.I)

def chk_str(s):
    first = chk_first(s)
    print('Первый символ: {}'.format(first if first is not None else 'недопустимых символов нет')) 
    rest = chk_rest(s)
    print('Остальные символы: {}'.format(rest if rest else 'недопустимых символов нет'))                                                                                             
s = input("Введите строку:")
print('Проверяем строку: {}'.format(s))
chk_str(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import string

s1 = {'_'} | set(chr(ord('а') + i) for i in range(33)) | {'ё'} \
     | set(chr(ord('А') + i) for i in range(33)) | {'Ё'} \
     | set(string.ascii_letters)

s2 = s1 | set('0123456789')

def chk_str(s, s1=s1, s2=s2):
    print('Первый символ: {}'.format(s[0] if s[0] not in s1 else 'недопустимых символов нет'))
    if set(s[1:]).difference(s2):
        print('Остальные символы: {}'.format(set(s[1:]).difference(s2)))
    else:
        print('Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет')
```

Примеры:

```
In [49]: chk_str('abc_123')
Первый символ: недопустимых символов нет
Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет

In [50]: chk_str('!abc_123')
Первый символ: !
Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет

In [51]: chk_str('!abc_123$')
Первый символ: !
Остальные символы: {'$'}

In [52]: chk_str('abc_123$')
Первый символ: недопустимых символов нет
Остальные символы: {'$'}

In [53]: chk_str('abc%_123$')
Первый символ: недопустимых символов нет
Остальные символы: {'$', '%'}
```

---

альтернативно множество `s1` можно задать перечислив все буквы и знак подчеркивания:

```
s1 = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzЁАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяё')
```

Comment: Я признаю,что формально вы ответили на мой вопрос,но хотелось бы вариант решения попроще ибо то,что вы написали трудно понять мне как начинающему программисту.Если моя просьба вас не устраивает,прошу объяснить подробно как решить задачу,но проще.

Comment: @Noob_Prog, какая часть кода вызывает у вас вопросы/затруднения?

Comment: s1 = {'_'} | set(chr(ord('а') + i) for i in range(33)) | {'ё'} \
     | set(chr(ord('А') + i) for i in range(33)) | {'Ё'} \
     | set(string.ascii_letters)

Comment: @Noob_Prog, добавил упрощённый вариант создания множества `s1`

Comment: Благодарю за понимание

Comment: Max U,упрощённый вариант с точки зрения загрузки оперативной памяти хуже чем первый?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, упрощенный вариант хуже тем, что надо вручную задавать все символы... С точки зрения использования памяти мы говорим о нескольких сотнях байт...

Comment: вы имеете ввиду что во втором варианте мы используем на несколько сотен байт больше?

Comment: оба варианта в итоге будут занимать одинаковое количество памяти. Я имею в виду, что здесь экономия памяти неуместна...

Comment: set(chr(ord('а') + i) for i in range(33))  здесь кодируется строка из русских букв нижнего регистра,а set(chr(ord('А') + i) for i in range(33)) кодирует строку из русских букв верхнего регистра?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, да, вы все правильно поняли

Comment: set(string.ascii_letters) а это для латинских?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86544/discussion-between-maxu-and-noob-prog).